# I'm having an issue with syntax in a Stored SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add three additional columns to a stored procedure (I don't have a lot of experience in stored procedures), the columns are Family ID, Address, and Phone No. Although I've run the query and confirmed the syntax for my select statement is correct, when I add the statement to the stored proc, I receive the following error: Incorrect syntax near 'capPrograms'(this would be line 14). I know this probably has to do with hoe I'm trying to implement my statement in the procedure to update it, but I'm not quite sure what the issues as I've tried several changes with similar or more extensive errors. Any assistance is appreciated, I've included the block of code I'm working with below:

```
SELECT  capCase.Id AS capCase_Id,
            capCase.DateApplied AS capCase_DateApplied,
            CASE 
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(#cases.origCaseYear)=1 THEN CAST(origCaseYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST(capCase.IdYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR)
                WHEN #cases.maxRolloverYear IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(capCase.IdYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST(#cases.MaxRolloverYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR)
                ELSE CAST(capCase.IdYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR) 
            END AS capCase_IdYear,
      Person.id as Person_id,
            Person.LastName + ', ' + Person.FirstName AS PersonPrint_Name,
person.idFamily AS Family_ID, person.homePhone AS Phone_No,  (SELECT family.physicalAddress1+ ', ' + family. physicalAddressCity+ ' ' +family. physicalAddressZip) AS Address
 FROM Family
LEFT JOIN person ON family.Id = person.idFamily;

capPrograms.Program AS capPrograms_Program,
            capStatus.Status AS capStatus_Status,
            #lastFollowup.followupDate AS capCaseFollowup_Date,
            CASE
                WHEN capCase.IdCaseWorker IS NULL THEN 'No Worker Assigned'
                ELSE caseWorker.LastName + ', ' + caseWorker.FirstName + ISNULL('<' + caseWorker.EmailWork + '>', '')
            END AS capCase_IdCaseWorker, 
            capcaseDenialReason.reason AS capCase_idDenialReason,
```

Comment: `I've run the query and confirmed the syntax for my select statement is correct`.  I doubt it....Whatever you have posted will definitely not run.

Comment: I ran this and it provided results. SELECT person.idFamily AS Family_ID, person.homePhone AS Phone_No,  (SELECT family.physicalAddress1+ ', ' + family. physicalAddressCity+ ' ' +family. physicalAddressZip) AS Address
 FROM Family
 LEFT JOIN person ON family.Id = person.idFamily;

Comment: That's not all you posted.  What's the stuff on line 14 and below?  Doesn't even make sense to be there.

Comment: Format your code properly!!  Learn to use table alias.

Comment: Right, so I'm trying to get assistance on how to convert a query into a stored procedure or how to update a procedure properly. I'm currently looking into this on various sources but was wondering if there was any assistance that could be provided to point me in the right direction. If you're uncertain, that's fine, I appreciate your taking the time to review it in any event. Thanks.

Comment: `"I've run the query and confirmed the syntax for my select statement is correct"`.  Really???  There are tons of error in your query.  How could it run???

Comment: @K.Kingsberry Without table structures, without sample input, without expected output, without explanation what you really want to achieve, with definitely broken query, how do you expect us to help you???  We are not magician.

Comment: I just pointed out the SELECT statement that I'm trying to integrate. Again, I'm new to SQL so am getting the hang of it as I walk through different tutorials. It's just question, Eric, not really an emotion inducing statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long to comment, so I added a bunch of comments in your code. You have, A LOT of issues.

```
SELECT  
    capCase.Id AS capCase_Id,
    capCase.DateApplied AS capCase_DateApplied,
    CASE 
        --here you are referencing a temp table, which isn't joined below
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(#cases.origCaseYear)=1 THEN CAST(origCaseYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST(capCase.IdYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR)
        WHEN #cases.maxRolloverYear IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(capCase.IdYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST(#cases.MaxRolloverYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR)
        ELSE CAST(capCase.IdYear + 2004 AS VARCHAR) 
    END AS capCase_IdYear,
    Person.id as Person_id,
    Person.LastName + ', ' + Person.FirstName AS PersonPrint_Name,
    person.idFamily AS Family_ID, 
    person.homePhone AS Phone_No,  

    --this subquery as no from clause... that's an issue... you probably want to remove it completly and replace it with the one below
    (SELECT family.physicalAddress1+ ', ' + family. physicalAddressCity+ ' ' +family. physicalAddressZip) AS Address,
    --this is likely what you want
    family.physicalAddress1 + ', ' + family. physicalAddressCity + ' ' + family. physicalAddressZip AS AddressCorrected

FROM Family
LEFT JOIN person ON 
family.Id = person.idFamily;   --you have a ; here, which terminates the statement. Everything else below isn't included

--Here you need to join the capPrograms and #lastFollowup table..

--here, you listed some columns, without a table reference. You need to join the table above, and move these columns above the FROM clause
            capPrograms.Program AS capPrograms_Program,
            capStatus.Status AS capStatus_Status,
            #lastFollowup.followupDate AS capCaseFollowup_Date,
            CASE
                WHEN capCase.IdCaseWorker IS NULL THEN 'No Worker Assigned'
                ELSE caseWorker.LastName + ', ' + caseWorker.FirstName + ISNULL('<' + caseWorker.EmailWork + '>', '')
            END AS capCase_IdCaseWorker, 
            capcaseDenialReason.reason AS capCase_idDenialReason,
```

Comment: Thank you for the edits. I'll add your suggestions and test it out.